# which dictionary or hashtable's key can be symbol expression?

Tags: python, sympy

1. would like to store a list of ideals as values
   and use a polynomial or a function as key in dictionary or hashtable

   dict[x^2+x+1] = x+1

which function can it do this like table function in maple?

show as this

```
 dict[x^2+x+1] = [x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4, x+5]
 dict[x^3] = [x+1, x+2]
```

2. do sympy have hilbert function? since i use hilbert function as key in dictionary

Comment: this can carry some meaning , can you show an example of your data that want to store ?

Comment: You can easily use a function, but what you wrote is just an expression (and not even a polynomial, since `^` doesn't mean exponentiation in Python).  Can you explain what you want to do with this?  If you already have your polynomials defined as Python functions, you can just use them as-is.

Comment: i use hilbert function as key in dictionary, do it have hilbert function?

Comment: @BrenBarn the expressions are SymPy expressions, which are unevaluated objects. You are right that the exponentiation should be `**`, though.

Answer (score 0):

SymPy is just a Python library, so you have all of Python at your disposal when you use it. Python has a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) type built in.

```
>>> a = {x: 1}
>>> a[x**2 + 1] = 2
>>> a
{x: 1, x**2 + 1: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

And the values can be lists:

```
>>> {x**2 + x + 1: [x+1, x+2]}
{x**2 + x + 1: [x + 1, x + 2]}
>>> d = _
>>> d[x**2 + x + 1].append(x+3); d
{x**2 + x + 1: [x + 1, x + 2, x + 3]}
```